# SQl Server Average Hours per day

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to Calculate average hours for week.

e.g. My Weekly hours are 44:43  (hh:mm) and my Working days are 5 
then it should return **8:57**

44:43/ 5 ==> 8:57

How i can achieve in SQL Server.

Comment: how are you storing this weekly hours in database? is it single varchar column or two different integer columns or something else?

Comment: I am storing it as single varchar column '44:43'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the query that I have constructed as per your requirements:

```
DECLARE @TotalHours VARCHAR(5) = '44:43'


SELECT CAST(CAST(AvgMinutes AS INT)/60 AS VARCHAR) + ':'
        + CAST(CAST(AvgMinutes AS INT)%60 AS VARCHAR)
FROM (
        SELECT CEILING((CAST(LEFT(@TotalHours,CHARINDEX(':',@TotalHours) - 1) AS INT ) * 60 
           + CAST(RIGHT(@TotalHours,LEN(@TotalHours) - CHARINDEX(':',@TotalHours)) AS INT ))/5.0) AvgMinutes
     ) AS TotalMinutes
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the time to seconds, then divide, and convert back to time format.  Assuming that `WeeklyHours` are in a `time` format, something like this:

```
select dateadd(second, datediff(second, 0, WeeklyHours) / WorkingDays, cast(0 as time))
```

This expression should definitely work if `WeeklyHours` is stored as a `datetime`.

Comment: Hi,Gordon Linoff,Thanks for your quick response but it is not working as my hours is 44 which is not in acceptable as time.

Comment: @bunty . . . How are you representing it then?

Comment: :- I am storing it as single varchar column '44:43'

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(INT,DATEPRT(HH,WH))/5)+':'+
        +CONVERT(VARCHAR,(CONVERT(INT,DATEPRT(HH,WH))%5*60+CONVERT(INT,DATEPRT(mm,WH)))/5)
fROM TIME
```

Answer (score 0):

Not getting the calculation. What I am trying to get is (44 + (43 / 60)) / 5. I did 43/60 to convert the mins to hours. As per this requirement, the query comes as

```
select (cast(SUBSTRING(Data, 1, charindex(':',Data,1) - 1) as int) + 
    (cast(SUBSTRING(Data, charindex(':',Data,1) + 1, len(Data)) as decimal(18,2)) / 60)) / 5
from tblWorkHours
```